# Limiting recorded video size in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I wonder whether there is a way to limit recorded videos *size* in iOS. I know one can limit *duration*, but it seems to me there is no way to limit the actual *size* instead, at least I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: VideoSize = (sizeOfOneFrame*FPS*duration)+/-(encoding||compression). You can plug in some (hopefully conservative) estimates for each of those values, and try to estimate the duration you need to limit to.

Comment: compression if obviously a big unknown here - a more or less static frame can be compressed very effectively and this can have a huge diff in terms of the resulting duration for the same file size. Somehow it looks like Android camera controllers are able to deduce the file size on the fly but not iOS...